# Where is the sessions hash in the Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, web, google-chrome-devtools

I'm storing a counter in the sessions hash that gets incremented every time I call the `index` action in the `Store` controller.

I'm printing it out in the `Store` view, as shown in the code and screenshot.

I know I can "reset the counter" by deleting the cookie, shown in the screen shot. And I know I print the sessions hash on the server. But how do I see the sessions hash in the chrome dev tools?

store_controller.rb

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order(:title)
    session[:counter] ||= 0
    session[:counter] += 1
  end
end
```

store/index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>
<p><%= session[:counter] %></p>
<% p session %>

<% cache @products do %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <% cache product do %>
      <div class="entry">
        <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
        <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
        <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
        <div class="price_line">
          <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
          <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product) %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

screenshot

[image]

Comment: What session storage strategy are you using? In any case, don't expect to be able to access the session contents from the browser, the contents aren't always in the browser at all and if they are, they'll be encrypted to prevent people from looking at it or changing things.

Comment: Not sure, I'm using whatever the default rails 5 strategy is. I read [a blog post](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/) and found this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html) that seems like it might be good reading to educate myself more :) I thought that the session was stored in the browser, it looks like it's only the cookie that's stored, so it's more complex than I originally thought

Comment: Sometimes the cookie is the whole session, sometimes it is just an ID referencing something stored server-side. In either case, the cookie will be encrypted to prevent tampering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login#sec-a_working_log_in_method) the sessions hash is encrypted so you wouldn't be able to view it in plain text from the browser.